# The right metrics to monitor AWS Glue Jobs

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, aws-glue, datadog

What're the right Glue metrics that allow to monitor the status of the glue jobs

> Know that status of the last run (OK or KO) & the number of Success/Failed executions

PS: In order to explore the metrics, I'm using Datadog